# C++ Priority Queue with Custom Compare Function not Behaving Correctly on Push()

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, priority-queue

I have defined a C++ priority queue like this:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, decltype(&mygreater)> frontier(&mygreater);
```

with a custom mygreater function() like this:

```
bool mygreater(pair<int,int> v1, pair<int,int> v2) {
        return v1.first > v2.first;
}
```

However, when I try to push a vector of pairs of ints onto the priority queue, I keep getting a ton of errors, including:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >, bool (*)(std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<int, int>)>::push(std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >&)’ frontier.push(temp);
```

Might anyone know what is causing the errors on my attempts to push to the priority queue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you currently pushing the vector of pairs of ints into the queue?

Comment: basically like this: temp.push_back(make_pair(sr,sc));
        frontier.push(temp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with your custom comparison. You get the same error if you do this:

```
std::priority_queue<int> q;
std::vector<int> v;
q.push(v);
```

`std::priority_queue::push` takes a single object of whatever type you're storing, not a whole vector of them. The type you're storing is `pair<int,int>`, but you're trying to push `vector<pair<int,int>>`.

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize that in my declaration, the vector<pair<int,int>> portion was just defining the underlying container of the queue itself. The first argument should actually be a vector. I appreciate the help!